# how can I disable copying images from browsing my website

Tags: javascript, mobile

There is an option for disabling right click on the website on the computer but on the mobile I don't know which javascript code I would need.

Comment: It's impossible.  Anyway people can still get your images without right-click.

Comment: "disabling right click" is completely pointless. It's 2013 not 1998

Comment: Following up on the "disabling right click" point... almost all browsers have developer tools built in. Pressing **CTRL + U** or **F12** will reveal everything about the page/site you are on.

Answer (score 7):

Images have to be copied from the web server to the client system in order for the client system to display them.

There is no way to stop people from saving them.

> There is an option for disabling right click on the website

Not one that can't be trivially bypassed.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to actually block an image from being copied. If it's being shown to the user, they can obtain it. The resource is already sent to them for render anyways.